# Normalisers and connectedness of parabolic subgroups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected affine algebraic group over an algebraically closed field. A *parabolic subgroup* of $G$ is a subgroup $P$ such that $G/P$ is a complete variety. This is equivalent to $P$ containing some Borel subgroup $B$ of $G$. In Humphreys' *Linear Algebraic Groups*, exercise 21.10, one has to prove the following:

*Let $B$ be a Borel subgroup of $G$. Then $B = N_G(B)^{\circ}$ (and similarly for parabolic subgroups).*

For a Borel subgroup, I did the following: $B$ is a normal Borel subgroup of $N_G(B)^{\circ}$, so the variety $N_G(B)^{\circ}/B$ is complete, irreducible and affine, i.e. a point. Thus $B = N_G(B)^{\circ}$. However this does not generalise to parabolics without proving that all parabolics are connected. Is there a way to use this property of Borel subgroups to prove that parabolic subgroups are connected?

Comment: Hmm, so your argument should work for $P^0$, but the normalizer of $P^0$ contains $P$, and anything that normalizes $P$ also normalizes $P^0$. It seems like this should combine to show the result for $P$ without directly showing that $P = P^0$ (though as far as I recall, parabolics are indeed connected).